# TYPO3 fluid f:image without width/height attribute / f:uri.image issues

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-8.x

I'm having some trouble getting `{f:uri.image}` to work, this doesn't render:

```
<img src="{f:uri.image(src:person.firstImage,treatIdAsReference:1, width:150c,height:150c,cropVariant:'square')}"/>
```

`person.firstImage` is of type `TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference`.

Maybe you spot the error?

On the other hand, this works:

```
<f:image class="image-author" image="{person.firstImage}" width="150c" height="150c" cropVariant="square"/>
```

... but then the output will always feature the `width="150" height="150"` html attributes, which will conflict with responsive CSS.

Is there a way to prevent `f:image` from outputting with and height in the source tag? Probably not, if I look at [the VH](https://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/8/html/fluid_2_classes_2_view_helpers_2_image_view_helper_8php_source.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the width and height when adding `c`

`<img src="{f:uri.image(src:person.firstImage,treatIdAsReference:1, width:'150c',height:'150c',cropVariant:'square')}"/>`

Would also go for:

`<img src="{f:uri.image(image:person.firstImage,width:'150c',height:'150c',cropVariant:'square')}"/>`

Comment: Oh! Thanks a bunch! Apparently, it's `image` not `src` right? Is it wrong in 
 https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/Uri/Image.html ?

Comment: `image` is preferred and faster